# htaccess to create centralize php files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have no idea how to achieve the following.

Currently I have a problem. Whenever a user goes to www.example.com or any link with same domain it will run a centralize.php (example). This PHP script will determine which PHP to call based on the links, something like centralized php files.

I tried to use .htaccess to achieve this without success. What am I doing wrong or is there are another way to do this?

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule /(.*) /iindex4.php$1 [PT]
```

The above is what I've tried so far but it does't meet my requirement and is obviously flawed or buggy.

Question summary
- navigate any url with same domain it will run a certain PHP file
- is there another way to do this beside .htaccess

Comment: coz I never tried Kohana be4. thx for your suggeestion

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't meet my requirement and is obviously flawed or buggy"? What issues are you experiencing? What requirement isn't it meeting?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then you can retrieve the requested URI from the script through the `$_GET['q']` variable.

Comment: What would happen if you had a search page which needed the query string `q`?

Comment: That may be a problem. It would suffice to change the name of the parameter either in the PHP script or in the .htaccess file. However, for a more elegant solution, see @GolezTrol's answer.

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess is the way to do this, and this approach is commonly used, for instance by mediawiki, wordpress, and frameworks like Kohana.

To redirect everything to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

To allow existing files to be executed (which is not what you want, I guess):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```